# Developing android apps for Zebra devices

Tags: java, android, maps, zebra-printers, geotagging

My simple query is that how different are the zebra devices from normal android devices?
Also if we develop android apps for normal android devices will it work on zebra devices?or vice versa?
Also what are the android versions supported on Zebra devices?
we need to have simple app with GPS trailing/tracking and data entry on zebra devices?

Can any one suggest how to start with development?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Zebra offers two variants of android running on their devices, GMS or non-GMS (Google Mobility Services).   In either case you will have access to all the standard Android APIs but on GMS devices you also have access to the full range of Google Play Services.  You can develop an application that runs on both Zebra and non-Zebra devices, the only complication is the scanning SDK (EMDK) will need to be specified in your gradle file in rather than as an add-in (http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-4/guide/programming_practices/#emdkasadependencyinbuildgradle).  The version(s) of Android supported on Zebra devices vary depending on the device type, most of the devices right now are running Lollipop or Marshmallow.  Not all devices support GPS (since some are targeted for indoor use-cases like warehouses) so make sure your device supports that.

The best place to start development would be the Zebra docs page which gives an overview of your development options: http://techdocs.zebra.com/help/

For transparency, I work for Zebra

Comment: I have developed android app which running background services to net connection changes but that is no working in Zebra device, could you help me regarding this

Comment: There should be no differences in your application's behaviour when running on a Zebra or non-Zebra device, if we are just talking about running a background service.